# Why was the bad guy in Osmosis Jones called a virus?

Tags: plot-explanation, osmosis-jones

In the 2001 animated movie, *Osmosis Jones*, a microbe called Thrax enters a human's body and makes him ill. Osmosis Jones who is a white blood cell should stop the germ before the human dies.

While Thrax is short for Anthrax (which is a bacterial disease), the microbe is referred to as a virus in the movie.

Was it a mistake by the screenwriters?

Comment: According to imdb Thrax is not anthrax. He is a virus that operates unlike any known disease. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181739/trivia/?item=tr5726489&ref_=ext_shr_lnk

Comment: But why did they choose a name similar to anthrax for him?

Comment: That would be a different question than the one you asked.

Comment: Similar question with a great answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244003/what-kind-of-virus-is-thrax-from-osmosis-jones/244011#244011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this one on another site. In short, Thrax's character was rewritten (repeatedly), but he was original *a cold virus*.

> Thrax was originally conceived as ["a common cold"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold), then re-written as the "[*Hong-Kong flu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_flu)" when the makers thought that they might get Jet-Li attached to the film. Over time he became less specific and more tropey, ending up as **Scarlet Fever**....
>
> > "*La Muerte Roja!*" [The Red Death]
>
> .... but with inconsistencies that likely exist because of how the script was persistently re-written. You might also want to note that he's literally scarlet and persistently hums the tune "*[Fever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=19&v=UFpshq8fCGI&feature=youtu.be)*".
>
> > **Q:** *That's what I was going to ask.  When you pitched this, what has really changed since then?*
> >
> > **Marc:** *Well, a few things changed.  In the very original...very little has changed from the actual pitch.  I have the pitch cards I used when I pitched the story.  I did conceive it originally that the whole thing would just be about...have you seen the movie yet?*
> >
> > **Q:** Yes.
> >
> > **Marc:** ***Would just be about a common cold.**  At the end of the movie, in the pitch, his wife said - Frank had a wife, not a daughter at the time - said, "Honey, are you feeling okay?" He said, "I thought I was getting sick there for a minute, but I guess I'm going to be okay," like the whole movie was that.*
> >
> > **Zak:** *It was a counterpoint between how little he cared in real life versus how much we cared in the movie.*
> >
> > **Marc:** *Yeah, and it wasn't a change...it was a change that I think we wanted to make to make the stakes greater and make it a life or death illness.  That's one change.  **Thrax was originally conceived as the Hong Kong flu who was a bad ass Asian virus - sort of a Jet Li character.  Other than that...the live-action...***
> >
> > <sub><sup>[INTERVIEW WITH THE SCREENWRITER & PRODUCER](http://am.animatedviews.com/OsmosisJones.html)</sup></sub>

As to his name, there's no good reason to assume that just because his name is Thrax that he's anthrax. Indeed, the symptoms he causes are nothing like it.